# Can three web-pages be inside the same project in Firebase (Firebase Hosting)?

Tags: html, css, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

Let's say I created a project in Firebase called ExampleApp.

I created a page with a form to be submitted. It is being hosted by Firebase. The database (Cloud Firestore) is storing the data submitted by the user when he/she fills the form and click on the submit button.

There should be a way to present this data beautifully to the person who is responsible for analyzing it.

**So, some specific person responsible for reading the data need to be able to login with some credentials created by me and then see the data beautifully organized.**

So, given the fact that I need to create another webpage (or anything that allows me to accomplish my task), such that the admin can access through authentication (a page with username/password form) and get to see the database in a beautiful layout, do I need to create another project in Firebase?

**It would be great If I could achieve all of this inside the same project in Firebase, but it seems Firebase hosting can only host a single web-page, right?**

They can all have the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add as many pages as you want in your Firebase hosting directory, along the index.html page (which you could rename by the way). You can even organised them with sub-directories. All of that within one Firebase project.

What is important to understand is that your pages are not going to be protected by authentication/authorization, but rather **the data which is displayed in the pages**.

For example, your page with the "data beautifully organised" could be acccessed by anybody who has its URL, but without the correct authentication/authorization the user will not see the data which is supposed to be displayed in this page, coming from the Firebase database (Real Time DB or Firestore). You ensure that by setting the correct security rules at the level of the database.

So, to say it with other words, the **containers** are totally public (for the ones who know how to call them with their URL) but the **content** is protected by the Firebase authentication mechanism **AND** the security rules you have declared at the database level (authorization).

Comment: Ok. So it's possible to have multiple html files inside the 'public' folder. How do I transit from one page to another? Can you give me an example?

Comment: You do it exactly like you would do in a "standard" HTML site which is composed of a set of pages. By having links between these pages with `<a href="...">` tags. Now, if you use a front end framework like, for example, Vue.js or Angular the links (and the navigation) would be done through the use of routers, but at the end it is the same mechanism.

Comment: Note that you could have "dynamic links" i.e. generate in one page an hyperlink which hold the ID of a Firestore document, like `https://xxxxx/displayUser.html?userId=AZERTY1234` and in the `displayUser.html` get the userId via the queryString, fetch the data for user `AZERTY1234` from the database and display its details.

Comment: Awesome Renaud! So, for every web-page I am having separate html/css and js files. Do I need to initialize things in html (as told by the firebase docs) and put the `var config = { apiKey: "xxxx", etc..}` and afterwards the `firebase.initializeApp(config);` inside every `.js` file that deals with firebase logic?

Comment: In this case, yes the Firebase configuration shall be repeated for all pages.